# Takes Time To Load Bootloader

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, bios, grub

I have a Lenovo Z510 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 dual boot. When I turn the laptop on, it takes about 15 to 20 seconds to load the grub menu and it shows the Lenovo Logo during this time. After that when I select my OS it boots normally.
And also when I restart the laptop it shows Grub menu in normal time (about 2 or 3 seconds).

Comment: Are you using UEFI or BIOS/CSM? If it's UEFI, can you post the output of `efibootmgr` from Linux?

Comment: Examine the disk's SMART data. Post it here if you wish an opinion.